# Composite function of two conjugate linear mappings - still conjugate linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, complex-geometry

The function $ f : \mathbb C^{2\times1} \rightarrow \mathbb C^{2\times1}$ is a conjugate linear transformation and has a coordinate matrix $ <\mathbf E^{*}, f(\mathbf E)>=E_2$ in respect to standard basis $ \mathbf E$ of $\mathbb C^{2\times1}$. Further, a basis $B=(b_1, b_2)$ (of $\mathbb C^{2\times1}$) is given, with:

$$ b_1=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0\\
        -i \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ b_2=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -i\\
        1+i \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

We are supposed to calculate the coordinate matrix of the function in respect to $B$ and to verify if a composite function $f\circ f=f^2$ is also a conjugate linear transformation, or a simple linear one?

I thought of multiplying the coordinate matrix of a function $f$ with itself in order to obtain a matrix of $f\circ f$ and then to multiply this what I got with a generic vector in $\mathbb C^{2\times1}$ such as:
$$ b_2=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a+bi\\
        c+di \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

to see if i get the conjugate complex function, but I don't know if that's the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check directly how the composition $f \circ f$ behaves. If $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$ then

$$ (f \circ f)(a v) = f(f(av)) = f(\overline{a} f(v)) = \overline{\overline{a}} (f(f(v))) = a ((f \circ f)(v)). $$

This shows that the composition of an anti-linear map with itself is linear.

Comment: This means that it's a general case, or is it a case specific for $\mathbb C^2$?

Comment: It's a general case - you can replace $\mathbb{C}^2$ with any complex vector space.